# Trying to set up grind pane correctly

Tags: java, javafx, layout

I'm starting learning and I want to set GridPane like in the screenshot:
[PIC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj4ad.png)
But it looks like this :[PIC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFEr9.png)

I will be very grateful for any tips on how to achieve layout from PIC1.
Is the grid pane good for this? My main issue is that the buttons or labels stick to their columns resizing the other columns.

Code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

final double MAX_FONT_SIZE = 30;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

    Thread superThreat = new Thread();
    superThreat.start();


    Label mainClicksWindow = new Label("0");
    mainClicksWindow.setMinSize(200,100);
    mainClicksWindow.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    mainClicksWindow.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    mainClicksWindow.setFont(new Font(MAX_FONT_SIZE));
    mainClicksWindow.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black; -fx-background-color: grey;");
    mainClicksWindow.setGraphic(new Label("main window"));
    mainClicksWindow.getGraphic().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #c4d8de;");



    Label timeRemainwindow = new Label("TIME");
    timeRemainwindow.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    Label infoLabel = new Label("INFO HERE");
    infoLabel.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

    Button coolButton = new Button("CLICK!");
    coolButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    coolButton.setMinSize(200,40);
    coolButton.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    Button button1 = new Button("1");
    button1.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

    Button button2 = new Button("2");
    button2.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    Button button3 = new Button("3");
    button3.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    Button button4 = new Button("4");
    button4.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    Button button5 = new Button("5");
    button5.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    Button button6 = new Button("6");
    button6.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    Button button7 = new Button("7");
    button7.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    Button button8 = new Button("8");
    button8.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);


    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(10.0);
    gridPane.setVgap(10.0);



    GridPane.setConstraints(mainClicksWindow,0,0);

    GridPane.setConstraints(infoLabel,0,1);
    GridPane.setConstraints(timeRemainwindow,1,1);

    GridPane.setConstraints(coolButton,0,2);

    GridPane.setConstraints(button1,0,3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button2,1,3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button3,2,3);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button4,3,3);

    GridPane.setConstraints(button5,0,4);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button6,1,4);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button7,2,4);
    GridPane.setConstraints(button8,3,4);

    borderPane.setCenter(gridPane);

    gridPane.getChildren().addAll(mainClicksWindow,infoLabel,timeRemainwindow,coolButton,button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 300, 250));
```

Comment: Use the `add(...)` method that allows you to specify a `colSpan` to let the controls you need span multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is have your elements span over multiple columns and or rows. For example, your top label to have a colspan of 2.

Change your setConstraints methods to include the rowspan and colspan arguments:

GridPane.setConstraints(mainClicksWindow,0,0,2,1);

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setConstraints-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-int-int-

You can also set this after your existing code by using setColumnSpan(Node child, Integer value) and setRowSpan(Node child, Integer value) for each Node where it is required.